# Weird behavoiur with route in Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes

I was modifying a code in order to show different data wether the user is super admin or not and I've found a weird behaviour I never have seen before:

The route file has these routes:

```
Route::resource('alert_levels','AlertLevelController');
Route::get('alert_levels/{id}','AlertLevelController@index');
```

And the controller looks like this:

```
public function index(Request $request){
  $user = Auth::user();
  $company_id = $user->isSuperAdmin() ? $request->company_id : $user->company_id;
  ...
}
```

The code works fine (only super admin would see a form in which there's a "company_id" input and therefore he/she will send the request parameter), but I've tried to access to the "admin URL" (alert_levels/*number*) with other user role in order to handle the code (redirect or other), and I've seen that the code looks like it's ingnoring it. It redirects to a blank page, and whatever I do the result is always a blank page. I even have written a dd('hello') on the top of the index controller method but the result is the same.

Please, do you know what I'm doing wrong or why is this the expected behavoiur?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to swap the routes, otherwise `resource` will evaluate the response (since it will define the same url structure/method) instead of the one you have defined:

```
Route::get('alert_levels/{id}','AlertLevelController@index');
Route::resource('alert_levels','AlertLevelController');
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm agree (stupid mistake, thanks for being me aware of it) but, I'm still wondering why even with a dd() call in the first line, it's ignoring it. It looks like as if it doesn't find the route (but I think it does because there's no error shown).

Comment: @cooper where do you have the dd?

Comment: @cooper This is the valid answer - please mark it as answered.